# Python парсинг vk foaf.php

Tags: python, парсер, вконтакте

Каким способом возможно спрарсить данные по ссылке https://vk.com/foaf.php?id=1 ?
Мне необходимо получить строчку с локацией (ya:location ya:city). 
Можно ли спарсить данные при помощи дефолтных библиотек python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, в стандартной библиотеке нету модуля для работы с форматом RDF/XML. Поэтому, я сделал парс с помощью [регулярных выражений](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Как Вы и просили, весь код работает с модулями из стандартной библиотеки. Версия питона: `3.7.4`

Код:

```
import urllib.request
import re

vk_link = "https://vk.com/foaf.php?id=1"
with urllib.request.urlopen(vk_link) as response:
   vk_xml = response.read().decode("windows-1251")

parsed_xml = re.findall(r'city="(.*)"', vk_xml)
for item in parsed_xml:
    print(item)
```